# VS_VERSIONINFO structure - unnecessary padding

Tags: data-structures, padding, memory-alignment, resource-files, versioninfo

I have taken the [VS_VERSIONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure from a file and the Value (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO) is padded with 32 bits.

According to MSDN, Value should be padded to fall on a 32 bit boundary.

> Padding1
>
> Type: WORD
>
> Contains as many zero words as necessary to align the Value member on a 32-bit boundary.

But value is already on a 32 bit boundary.
Why is VS_FIXEDFILEINFO padded with 32 bits on a 32 bit boundary, anyway?
To align data on a 32 bit boundary, only padding with less than 32 bits would make sense.

I'm asking this because I need to parse an RC script and generate this resource.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is added to structures and their members so that the CPU can access the memory holding those members using addresses that are aligned to the CPU's word width.

Back in the dark days some CPUs could be persuaded to generate a bus error if you did a non-aligned access but these days it's just slower, particularly if you miss the onboard caches.

`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` is arbitrary data of arbitrary length therefore some padding *may* appear after it to bring the subsequent `VS_VERSIONINFO` structure members back into alignment.

The wording of MS's documentation for the `wLength` member of `VS_VERSIONINFO` implies that you shouldn't consider padding between the `VS_VERSIONINFO` that you're looking at and the next one in memory. i.e. do not subtract the address of the next structure from the first one and use that as `wLength` because you may bring in some padding bytes between the two structures that you don't want.

Comment: Oh, so what they're trying to say is that wLength doesn't include any padding between VS_VERSIONINFO structures, not padding between its members. But still, szKey would already fall on a 32 bit boundary. Those 32 bits of padding are unnecessary. MS docs says "Padding1: Contains as many zero words as necessary to align the Value member on a 32-bit boundary. " But Value is already on a 32 bit boundary. It makes no sense to align data on 32 bit boundary with 32 bits padding. Only padding with less than 32 bits would make sense.

Comment: I think they're trying to say (not very clearly) that if the `VS_VERSIONINFO` structure itself did not start on a 32-bit boundary then `Padding1` is there to ensure that `Value` definitely will. To be fair, they do state at the end that this is not an actual language structure and just a convenient way to express the in-memory organization of the version resource. Reading between the lines and noting the padding units of 16-bits, I expect that this padding appeared during the migration of the structure from 16 to 32 bit Windows.

Comment: Oh my, I was blind. "VS_VERSIONINFO" it's a unicode string so it needs to be terminated with a null, so the szKey is 2 bytes longer than I actually marked in the picture, and the padding is actually 16 bits, not 32. Now it makes sense.

Comment: I'm also trying to read/write the resource, and I just want to mention that the documentation on VS_VERSIONINFO doesn't seem to be correct, at least not in the examples I have tried. it says 'padding2()' after the VS_FIXEDFILEINFO, but it seems that there is no padding2 as VS_FIXEDFILEINFO already ends on a 32 bit boundary, the first child begins right after VS_FIXEDFILEINFO without the padding2.